# Is there any Linux alternative for Windows Path API?

Tags: c++, linux, api, path

In Windows API there are a big set of methods for manipulating of paths and URLs at [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559.aspx). The functions include helpers like `PathAddBackslash`, `PathCanonicalize`, `PathCombine`, and `PathIsDirectory`.

The question is: are there any Posix provided functionality or Linux-based library that gives analogous functionality? That is, simplifies paths combination, canonicalization, parsing, as well as URLs parsing?

I know that it is possible to write such functions with C++ (not small but not complex job), but my question is: are there any ready "official" libraries on Linux that already have similar functionality?

Comment: boost.filesystem? though it doesn't do URLs I think

Comment: Have you looked into libcurl http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: take a look at [boost file system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite happy with boost_filesystem. Best part of it is that it is cross-platform, so it also works on Windows.

Another possibility is leveraging the capabilities of Qt or GLIB (GTK+).

Finally, most path-mangling operations are already in the POSIX standard and available out-of-the-box. For an example see the manpage of basename(3), dirname(3):
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dirname.3.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also use POCO C++ libraries, take a look here:

http://pocoproject.org/features.html

And here you could find more on filesystem api:

http://pocoproject.org/slides/080-Files.pdf